# GStreamer - Save depth map video from ZED 2

Tags: gstreamer, depth, gstreamer-1.0

I have a ZED 2 camera that gives me the not normalized depth map values (real depth values) in GRAY16_LE format and I want to save this information without loosing the real depth values (so I can process and normalize later). I've been using this pipeline to visualize without saving:

```
gst-launch-1.0 zedsrc stream-type=3 ! 'video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE' ! autovideoconvert ! queue ! fpsdisplaysink
```

And I tried converting the image to RGB and compressing to save in .avi format, but the values of the pixels loose their interpretation (it's no longer the real depth values and it doesn't seem like the normalized version of them).

```
gst-launch-1.0 zedsrc stream-type=3 ! 'video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE' !  videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=video.avi
```

Is there any way I can save the real depth values the stream gives me? What format should I use? I'm a little bit lost here.

Answer (score 0):

In general compressing (encoding) an image will change its pixel values, not even setting the jpegenc quality to 100 guarantees it. I believe that for your use case your only option is to save the raw file directly

```
gst-launch-1.0 zedsrc stream-type=3 ! 'video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE' ! filesink location=video.raw
```